# how to divide array which contains numeric and characters into two arrays and print them?

Tags: php

Here my question is how to divide an array which contains both numeric and characters. for example: 125 mg. I am getting this value from database and i am trying to split it but i am not able to divide it . Can anybody give the suggestions and i google a lot.

This is the code example:

```
<?php 
$sql="select * from medication_history where id=$id";
$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$dose=$row['dose'];
//echo $dose;
echo str_word_count($dose);
$dose=implode('',explode(',',$dose));
//print_r ($dose);
 echo $dose;?>
```

Comment: Please provide examples of input data and expected results, with corner cases.

Comment: hi, I am going to get the $dose variable as 125 mg so how to divide these two into numeric and character and print the above value in two places

Answer (score 0):

I think the most appropriate solution is to split the "dose" column in two distinct column.
First one containing the quantity (125), and the second one containing the unit (mg).

The other way I see is using regex to identify the numeric part, and the alpha characters part.

Answer (score 0):

if ı understand your problem. the answer is:

```
$num=preg_replace("#[^0-9]#",'', $dose);

$char=preg_replace("#[^a-z]#",'', $dose);
```

now:

$num=125 and $char=mg.